# If $\sum a_n$ is convergent, with $a_n \geq 0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, show that if $p > 1$, $\sum a_n^p$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Question: If $\sum a_n$ is convergent, with $a_n \geq 0$  $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, show that if $p > 1$, $\sum a_n^p$ converges.

Here's my proof. Can someone please verify it?

$\displaystyle{\left( \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k \right)^p \geq \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k^p} \geq 0$

Note that $\displaystyle{\left( \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k \right)^p}$ is bounded, since the sequence of partial sums $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k$ converges. Also, the sequence $s_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k^p$ is increasing. Therefore, by the monotone convergence theorem, $s_n$ converges.

Comment: Your proof seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

As $\sum a_n$ converges, there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\forall n \geq N \implies |a_n| < 1.$$

As $a_n \geq 0$, we have $$a_n^2 < a_n<1.$$

Thus by induction we get, $$a_n^p < a_n.$$

The result now follows from the Comparison Test.

**Remark:** Notice as $a_n \geq 0$, absolute convergence also sneaked in.